Fake Galileo telescopes at astronomy conference
In this century, I read a science fiction novel in which the main character was an astronomer (probably an alien first contact story). At one point the main character is remembering a conference he had gone to in Italy - while wandering the streets of the city, a peddler had sold him an antique telescope that he (the peddler) swore was one that Galileo had owned. At the first day of the conference itself, almost every attendee had an identical such telescope (and later, if I'm not misremembering, someone else was given a model radio telescope signed "Galileo Galilei").
It doesn't appear to be Benford's Eater, but I only have access to a paper copy to skim, so I might have missed the few paragraphs about the telescope incident

Happen to have Eater open, since I was reading it last month.  (I'm like a packrat when it comes to browser tabs.)  "Galil*" has no hits in the story.

Thsnk you for checking.
